# RVM multi-user install using gemset in home directories

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm currently trying to do a multi-user installation of RVM. The reason for this is that I'm creating a common linux ruby image to be used by multiple future projects and I don't know what user accounts will be using RVM. At the same time I'd like to allow the users to then to use gemsets without needing to rvmsudo/sudo.

The result I'm sort of hoping for (or an equivalent) is that users wont be able to install new rubies without sudo ability but they will be able to manage gems that live in their home directory with the convenience of 'rvm gemsets'.

Is this possible/ am I missing some config option? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM allows mixed mode, basically you can install rubies in system and use user gemsets.

1. Start with multi user installation.
2. Select manager user and add him to `rvm` group - he will be responsible to install new rubies.
3. For every user write `rvm user gemsets` - from this moment any gemset created by this user will be hosted in his HOME not in system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is inherently baked in to rvm, but with a little manipulation of rvm itself to check for a specific user or group before allowing the 'install' command to be processed you could easily accomplish what you're looking to do since rvm already supports a 'default' gemset and then gemsets in each user's $HOME.